# How to fix an UnsatisfiedLinkError for native cpp function in Android (ndk)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator, android-ndk

I am trying to run an easy Android ndk app in c, but I get UnsatisfiedLink Error for the stringFromJNI() function.

Any help would be appreciated. I am quite fluent in C, but my java is a little bit rusty. I have been trying a lot of tips from the web concerning naming, but so far no luck. Here are my files:

**hello-jni.c:**

```
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>


jstring
Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_stringFromJNI( JNIEnv* env,
                                                  jobject thiz )
{
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello from JNI !");
}
```

**Android.mk:**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := hello-jni
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hello-jni.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I compile this with ndk-build and all goes well, it provides me with a libnative.so, that is located in the project directory. I use eclipse for the rest.

**NdkFooActivity.java :**

```
package com.narola.Testndk;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

public class NdkFooActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ndk_foo);

        Log.i("comes at point","hay...");
        Log.d("value is : ",""+stringFromJNI());
    }

    public native String  stringFromJNI();
    public native String  unimplementedStringFromJNI();

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("hello-jni");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_ndk_foo, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Thank you for any suggestions, been searching for a few hours now!

Comment: http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/49.html implement this step by step tutorial and modify at parts you have to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the `hello-jni.c` file.
You have method signature in c file is `Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_stringFromJNI` else in your activity the package name is `com.narola.Testndk`.

The method signature has format like `Java_packagename_activityname_methodname` (In package name (.)Dot will be replaced by underscore).
In your case try like `Java_com_narola_Testndk_NdkFooActivity_stringFromJNI`

Comment: thanks for formatting my code and correct mistake.I have made changes according to your suggestion but it display same error.

Comment: I am confused in "HelloJni" of Java_com_narola_Testndk_HelloJni_stringFromJNI. Because I have filename with hello-jni.c so I have also tried to use Java_com_narola_Testndk_hello-jni_stringFromJNI but it display error in cygwin during compilation

Comment: I just added a missing part. please refer this

Comment: The method names in JNI are mangled according to the following official spec: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/design.html#wp615. In case of doubt, you can use **javah** utility to generate the C/C++ signatures for your native methods.